# how to iterate through each element of a unknown length of list while passed as argument to a function in python?

Tags: python, list

how can i modify the tab function to print the element 'c'?

```
  def tab(data):
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        print(i, v[0], v[1])

    tab([['a', 'b']])
    tab([['a', 'b', 'c']])
```

Result:

```
$ python3 tabulate2.py 
0 a b
0 a b
```

Comment: `print(i, *v)`?

Comment: You have to iterate, somehow, over *v* as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `str.join` or unpack the `v`:

```py
def tab(data):
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        print(i, *v)  # <-- put * here
        # or:
        #print(i, " ".join(v))


tab([["a", "b"]])
tab([["a", "b", "c"]])
```

Prints:

```
0 a b
0 a b c
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that the *join()* option is only applicable to lists with str elements whereas unpacking is a more general solution

Answer (score 0):

Some alternatives:

```
def tab(data):
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
      print(i, end=' ')
      for v_i in v: 
        print(v_i, end=' ')
      print()



def tab(data):
    for i, v in enumerate(data):
        print(i, ' '.join(v))



def tab(data):
    [print(i, ' '.join(v)) for i, v in enumerate(data)]
```

Comment: `join` works with `string`  list of string type